# How to get child component name which is active in HTML in parent component Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to fetch the child component name which is present in parent. On click of button available in parent component, I want to know the active child component in HTML currently.

Parent Component ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  active = true;
  anyFunction() {
    //changing tab status for child
  }
}
```

Parent Component html file

```
<div>
    <button (click)="anyFunction()"></button>
    <app-child1 *ngIf="active"></app-child1>
    <app-child2 *ngIf="!active"></app-child2>
 </div>
```

If I'm displaying child1 component, then when I click on button I want to know then I want to fetch Child1Component. The active one in HTML should be displayed.

Comment: you can send the text based on click event!

Comment: what do you mean by active? and on which base you make components active and inactive?

Comment: Its on basis of tab. But assuming if the child1 is active(means child2 is not in DOM or not loaded) Then I want to get the child1 component name.

Comment: So you want displayed component name in `anyFunction()`?

Comment: I want to know the child component name which is currently in DOM.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren